# Sorting a list of elements in a list based on last few characters

Tags: python-3.x

i have a list containing some server names like  ['ora04900', 'ora04901', 'ora04898', 'ora04903'].
How can i sort these server names based on the last 3 digits in each element of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [.sort](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method to sort your list and as the key you indicate through a lambda that you want to use only the last three digit (`x[-3:]`):

```py
servers = ['ora04900', 'ora04901', 'ora04898', 'ora04903']
servers.sort(key=lambda x: x[-3:])
```

Comment: can we add a check so see if there are 2 or 3 or 4 digits at the end of the servername,and then use the sort accordingly?

Comment: I don't think so, you need a have the same nomenclature for all servers name.

Comment: can we have a variable in place of -3 in key=lambda x: x[-3:]...like key=lambda x: x[-digit_position:]

Comment: @vivek Yes you can